# Updating the Windows location by using the mobile device GPS

Tags: android, windows, gps, location

I have an application that gets its position from the Windows location service (Through [System.Device.GeoCoordinateWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher)).

This was working fine on a HP Windows tablet (With builtin GPS) until somebody asked me to make this work on a non GPS Windows computer.

I was wondering if there is a way to update Windows location using an Android phone so using GeoCoordinateWatcher will get the position provided by the Android phone.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with external phone? Get the location on windows from android device or obtain location on android?

Comment: Have a look at https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-location-android

Comment: @BlackFlag, I've updated my question.  Thank you for the link but it only solves half the problem.  Getting the coordinates onto an Android device is not the complicated part of it (I think).  I would need to have that position sent to Windows (Either USB, Bluetooth, Wifi, etc.) to then update the Windows Location  service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it but it took two paid applications and the one on Windows is closed source and I would need to expand it...

So I've [asked another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138518/develop-a-windows-location-sensor-in-c-sharp) to develop something for the Windows part of my problem.

Here is how I answered my needs at first:

I installed an Android app called [Bluetooth GPS Output](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meowsbox.btgps) to output current Android phone position to an emulated serial port over bluetooth.

I then paired my cell phone to Windows, and went to the Bluetooth device properties to activate the "Serial Port" service.  Windows then associated a COM port to it.

Now I downloaded an application called [GPS Complete](https://www.gpssensordrivers.com/) an ran it on Windows.  After installing the GPS direct drivers (Directly in the application), Windows now had its position updated with the Android phone coordinates.

In my C# application, using `System.Device.GeoCoordinateWatcher` now returns me an updated position.

Simple wasn't it !?!