# Develop a Windows Location Sensor in C#

Tags: c#, windows, location, driver, sensors

Hello fellow developpers,

I need to develop an application that would get geographical coordinates from different sources and then update the Windows system location with these. (These sources could be NMEA streams, web service, or even manual inputs).

If I understood correctly, based on what I read on the Microsoft website ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/sensors/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/locationapi/windows-location-api-portal)) and over the Internet, I would need to develop my own Windows sensor driver to update this location of the system.

The goal is then to use the very simple [System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher) to obtain the system's position from any other application.

The documentation seems quite complete but does not contain any example.  Because it is my first Windows sensor driver, I'm completely lost on how and where I should begin.

Any clues on this that could help me getting started ?

C# would be great but C/C++ would obviously do it perfectly

Comment: You need to create an UMDF driver and this means C/C++. Perhaps my driver would suffice for you. https://www.gpssensordrivers.com

Comment: Thank you @Michael.  I'm already using your app.  It does the job but I would need to customize it a lot (I have 7 different geo coordinates sources. Some of them are standard (ie NMEA) and some other are completely custom.). Thank you.